# Error: Undefined name 'isRememberMe' Error: Required named parameter 'onChanged' must be provided

Tags: flutter, widget

When I'm trying to define isRememberme widget, some errors occurred. I'm trying to build a login app UI using flutter and android studio. I'm very new to this and struggling to find the error. I have highlighted the code that gives me error.

```
bool isRememberMe =false; //
```

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

Widget buildEmail() {
  return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Email',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight:
              FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 6,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2)
                  )
                ]
            ),

            height: 60,
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.email,
                    color: Color(0xff5ac18e),
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
            )
        )
      ],
  );
}

///////////////////////////////

Widget buildPassword() {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'Password',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight:
            FontWeight.bold
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    blurRadius: 6,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2)
                )
              ]
          ),

          height: 60,
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: true,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.lock,
                  color: Color(0xff5ac18e),
                ),
                hintText: 'Password',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
          )
      )
    ],
  );
}

Widget buildForgotPassBtn(){

  return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () => print("Forget Password pressed"),
     // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:0),
      child: Text(
        'Forgot Passsword?',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight : FontWeight.bold
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

**Widget buildRememberCb(){
  return Container(
    height: 20,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
       Theme(
          data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor :Colors.white),
          child: Checkbox(
            value: isRememberMe,
             ),
             )
            ],
          ),
        )
}
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool isRememberMe =false;**

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          Color(0x665ac18e),
                          Color(0x995ac18e),
                          Color(0xcc5ac18e),
                          Color(0xff5ac18e),
                        ]
                    )
                ),

                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 25,
                    vertical: 120,

                  ),

                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Sign In',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 40,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 50),
                      buildEmail(),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      buildPassword(),
                      buildForgotPassBtn(),
                      buildRememberCb(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move your `buildRememberCb` method to your `_LoginScreenState` class so you can use `setState` method as within the on change method of `CheckBox` widget.

```
Widget buildRememberCb({bool isRememberMe : false}){
    return Container(
      height: 20,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor :Colors.white),
            child: Checkbox(
              value: isRememberMe,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState((){
                  isRememberMe = value ?? false;
                });
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined all of your functions outside the scope of your widget. Since buildRememberCb function is outside the scope, you can't access isRememberMe variable here.

Also onChanged callback of Checkbox widget is required. You can't leave it undefined.

```
    class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool isRememberMe = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                      Color(0x665ac18e),
                      Color(0x995ac18e),
                      Color(0xcc5ac18e),
                      Color(0xff5ac18e),
                    ])),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 25,
                    vertical: 120,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text(
                        'Sign In',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 40,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 50),
                      buildEmail(),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      buildPassword(),
                      buildForgotPassBtn(),
                      buildRememberCb(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildEmail() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'Email',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 6,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2))
                ]),
            height: 60,
            child: const TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.email,
                    color: Color(0xff5ac18e),
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
            ))
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildPassword() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'Password',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      blurRadius: 6,
                      offset: Offset(0, 2))
                ]),
            height: 60,
            child: const TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.lock,
                    color: Color(0xff5ac18e),
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38)),
            ))
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildForgotPassBtn() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => print("Forget Password pressed"),
        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:0),
        child: const Text(
          'Forgot Passsword?',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildRememberCb() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 20,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Theme(
            data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white),
            child: Checkbox(
              value: isRememberMe,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                  isRememberMe = !isRememberMe;
                });
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```